# Table Column Misalignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

Please consider the following (http://jsfiddle.net/HaLGr/11/):

```
.head_row {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #5D7B9D;
}
.row_one {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.row_two {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
}
.row_three {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
}


<table name="main_table" id="main_tbl">
    <tr>
        <td class="head_row">Column 1</td>
        <td class="head_row">Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_one">
        <td>Row One</td>
        <td>Row One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_two">
        <td>Row Two</td>
        <td>Row Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_three">
        <td>Row Three</td>
        <td>Row Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why are the cells in third row misaligned when using ***display: block*** ?

[image]

I need to be able to hide (***display: none***) and show (***display: block***) the table rows with the correct column alignment.

Comment: By default, rows have `display: table-row;` set by the browser style sheet. Quite apparently it is quite different from `block`

Comment: Try using   visibility: hidden; /   visibility: visible; instead of display property if you want to toggle the visibility.

Comment: @techfoobar: Got it. Plz add your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, rows have `display: table-row;` set by the browser style sheet. And apparently it is quite different from `display: block`.

What you should instead do in your CSS is:

```
.row_three {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "display: block" with a table. I would say, do not use tables at all for what you are doing, try working with DIVs.